# Uso de List como origen datos Datagridview ordenado

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Actualmente tengo una consulta de base de datos muy pesada que recupera una gran cantidad de registros, pintar registro a registro en el datagrid es demasiado lento asi que mi solucion es recuperar la informacion a traves de un datatable y luego pasar esa datatable a una List para poder hacer operaciones con los datos recuperados, el caso es que me gustaria mostrar en el datagrid los campos de la lista pero con un orden determinado.

No encuentro la manera de asignar por ejemplo la Columna[0] del datagrid al campo Id del objeto del que se compone la lista.

Lamento no poder poner codigo porque es que realmente no se como hacerlo.
Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @lois6b , no he podido comprobar tu respuesta del todo ya que este tema me urge mas ahora mismo, pero en cuanto pueda lo miro, descuida.

Comment: Ok, perdona la insistencia haha es que dejo las preguntas en las que participo ahi hasta que se resuelven y la curiosidad me reconcome xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, por qué pasar el `DataTable` a una lista? Asigna directamente el `DataTable` al `DataSource` del `DataGridView`.

Segundo, un `DataGridView` puede autogenerar las columnas, o se las puedes definir tú. En el segundo caso, en cada `DataGridViewColumn` puedes definir con que columna del `DataTable` queda enlazado utilizando la propiedad `DataPropertyName`

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, el caso es que los datos que vienen de Base de datos han de ser tratado, realizar calculos con ellos y demas. La segunda parte de tu comentario me da una pista para intentar crear un nuevo datatable a partir de la lista que tengo y asignar esa tabla como datasource.

Comment: En un DataTable puedes tratar los datos exactamente igual que usando una Lista. Por otro lado, tambien puedes asignar la lista al datasource del datagridview y se aplica exactamente igual la segunda parte de la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendación és que directamente guardes la consulta sql en la Lista he aquí un ejemplo:

```
List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = query.ToString();

                SqlDataReader reader = null;
                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                        Object obj= new Object();
                        if(reader["a"] != DBNULL.Value)
                          obj.a = reader["a"];
                        objects.Add(obj);
                }
          }
       }
```

Una forma de ordenar la lista es:

```
objects.Sort((x, y) => -1 * x.a.CompareTo(y.a));
```

-1 * lo hace en Descendente para ordenar ascendente quita el -1 *

---

Edit

Por lo que veo me he dejado la parte de la presentacion he aqui un ejemplo, tienes que usar AutoGenerrateColumns="False" y montarte tu propia estructura de columnas con columns y BoundFields, como extra TemplateField que puedes poner lo que quieras LinkButtons o Datas con  %= Eval() %

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White" GridLines="Vertical" 
    CellPadding="4" BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99"></FooterStyle>
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" 
       BackColor="#F7F7DE"></PagerStyle>
    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
       BackColor="#6B696B"></HeaderStyle>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Titulo a mostrar" DataField="nombre de la propiedad del objeto" 
           SortExpression="nombre de la propiedad"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prueba">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# ComputeSeniorityLevel(DateTime.Now – 
                     (DateTime)Eval("HireDate")) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
         BackColor="#CE5D5A"></SelectedRowStyle>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE"></RowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

aquí mas información:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67520/GridView-Paging-and-Sorting

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Todo lo que se puede asignar desde el aspx se puede asignar desde c# para windowsforms tal que:

```
dgViewStudents.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgViewStudents.DataSource = bs;

DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "ID";
col.HeaderText = "ID Column";
col.Name = "foo";
dgViewStudents.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: En principio, la aplicación parece ser que es Winforms, no ASP

Answer (score 1):

Crea una clase con las propiedades que necesites:

```
public class Clase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

En tu método para la consult, crea una lista de tipo Clase.

```
public void Metodo()
    {
        List<Clase> Lista = new List<Clase>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                StringBuilder Query = new StringBuilder();

                Query.Append("SELECT * id,nombre,fecha FROM Tabla;");

                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = Query.ToString();

                SqlDataReader reader = null;
                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Clase obj = new Clase();
                    obj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
                    obj.Nombre = reader["nombre"].ToString();
                    obj.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["fecha"]);
                    Lista.Add(obj);
                }
            }
        }
        DataGridView.DataSource = Lista.OrderBy(b => b.Id).ToList();
    }
```

Asignas el datasource del DataGridView la lista.